# Weka: Supervised Discretize issue and error during attribute selection "Not enough training instances"

Tags: java, attributes, selection, weka, label

I've been learning the Weka API on my own for the past month or so (I'm a student).  What I am doing is writing a program that will filter a specific set of data and eventually build a bayes net for it, and a week ago I had finished my discretization class and attribute selection class. Just a few days ago I realized that I needed to change my discretization function to supervised and ended up using the default Fayyad & Irani method, after I did this I began to get this error in my attribute selection class:

```
Exception in thread "main" weka.core.WekaException: 
weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval: Not enough training instances with class labels (required: 1, provided: 0)!
at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1138)
at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1023)
at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
at weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval.buildEvaluator(CfsSubsetEval.java:331)
at weka.attributeSelection.AttributeSelection.SelectAttributes(AttributeSelection.java:597)
at weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection.batchFinished(AttributeSelection.java:456)
at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:663)
at AttributeSelectionFilter.selectionFilter(AttributeSelectionFilter.java:29)
at Runner.main(Runner.java:70)
```

My attribute selection before the change worked just fine, so I think that I may have done something wrong in my discretize class.  My other part of this question relates to that, because I also noticed that my discretize class does not appear to really be discretizing the data; it's just putting all the numeric data into ONE range, not binning it strategically like the Fayyad & Irani should.

Here is my discretize class:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal;

public class DiscretizeFilter
{
    private Instances data;
    private boolean sensitiveOption;
    private Filter filter = new Discretize();

    public DiscretizeFilter(Instances data, boolean sensitiveOption)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.sensitiveOption = sensitiveOption;
    }

    public Instances discreteFilter() throws Exception
    {
        NumericToNominal nm = new NumericToNominal();
        nm.setInputFormat(data);
        Filter.useFilter(data, nm);
        Instances nominalData = nm.getOutputFormat();

        if(sensitiveOption)//if the user wants extra sensitivity
        {
            String options[] = new String[1];
            options[0] = options[0];
            options[2] = "-E";
            ((Discretize) filter).setOptions(options);
        }
        filter.setInputFormat(nominalData);
        Filter.useFilter(nominalData,filter);
        return filter.getOutputFormat();
    }
}
```

Here is my attribute selection class:

```
import weka.attributeSelection.BestFirst;
import weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection;

public class AttributeSelectionFilter 
{
    public Instances selectionFilter(Instances data) throws Exception
    {
        AttributeSelection filter = new AttributeSelection();

        for(int i = 0; i < data.numInstances(); i++)
        {
            filter.input(data.instance(i));
        }
        CfsSubsetEval eval = new CfsSubsetEval();
        BestFirst search = new BestFirst();
        filter.setSearch(search);
        filter.setEvaluator(eval);

        filter.setInputFormat(data);
        AttributeSelection.useFilter(data, filter);

        return filter.getOutputFormat();
    }

    public int attributeCounter(Instances data)
    {
        return data.numAttributes();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Internally Weka stores attribute values as doubles. It appears that an exception was thrown because every single instance in your dataset (`data`) is "missing a class", i.e. was given an internal class attribute value NaN ("not a number") for whatever reason. I would recommend to double-check if `data's` class attribute was created/set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was my mistake of misunderstanding the description of the method "outputFormat()" in the Discretize class.  I instead got the filtered instances from the useFilter() and that solved my problems!  I was just giving the attribute selection filter the wrong type of data.